# Search Bar Controller with Table view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, swift2

I am new to Swift programming

SearchBar controller with tableview. I want display the multiple students in table view its working fine. I can add the search bar controller to table view and display the particular students data. table view cell contains the student information and image I want display particular student after search

this is the code

@IBOutlet var SearchBarDisp:UISearchBar!

```
override func viewDidLoad()
 {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar  
   }

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
//todo
}
```

I can get student data from json

```
func getKids(url : String) {

        UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        var errorCode = "1"

        var msg = "Failed"

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "getstaffstudents",
                                          relativeTo: URL(string: serverURL+"/rkapi/api/"))!)

        let session = URLSession.shared

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let bodyData = "staffId=\(staffId)"

        request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = session.dataTask(with:request,completionHandler:{(d,response,error)in

            do{

                if let data = d {

                    if let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

                        errorCode = String(describing: jsonData["errorCode"]!)

                        msg = jsonData["msg"] as! String

                       print("msg values",msg)

                        if errorCode == "0" {

                            if let kid_list = jsonData["students"] as? NSArray {

                                for i in 0 ..< kid_list.count {

                                    if let kid = kid_list[i] as? NSDictionary {

                                         kidHoleData.removeAll()

                                        let imageURL = url+"/images/" + String(describing: kid["photo"]!)

                                        self.kidsData.append(Kids(
                                            studentId: kid["studentId"] as? String,
                                            name:kid["name"] as? String,
                                            classId : kid["classId"] as? String,
                                            standard: ((kid["standard"] as? String)! + " " + (kid["section"] as? String)!),
                                            photo : (imageURL),
                                            school: kid["schoolName"] as? String,
                                            schoolId : "1",
                                            url : url)
                                        )
                                    }


                                }
                                self.loopCount += 1

                                self.do_table_refresh()
                             }

                        } else {
                            self.displayAlert("Kids", message: msg)
                        }

                    } else {

                        self.displayAlert("Kids", message: "Data Not Available. Please try again")

                    }
                }else {

                    self.displayAlert("Kids", message: "Please try again")

                }

            } catch let err as NSError {

                print("JSON Error \(err)")
            }
        })

        task.resume()
    }
```

Table view

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return (kidsData.count == 0) ? 0 : 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return kidsData.count


    }


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell =
            tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
                withIdentifier: "Kidscell", for: indexPath) as! KidsTableViewCell

        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let bounds = cell.bounds

        maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 3, y: 3, width: bounds.width-15, height: bounds.height-15), cornerRadius: 2).cgPath
        cell.layer.mask = maskLayer

        let row = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row
        if(kidsData.count>0){

            let kid = kidsData\[row\] as Kids
            cell.kidNameLabel.text = kid.name
            cell.classLabel.text = kid.standard
            cell.kidNameLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            cell.kidNameLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            cell.kidImageView.image = UIImage(named: "profile_pic")
            cell.kidImageView.downloadImageFrom(link: kid.photo!, contentMode: UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit)  //set your image from link array.

        }
        return cell

    }
```

I want display particular student in table view(like if I can search student name as vani  it's display the student vani in table view) pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy the hole data in to the attendanceInfoDupilicate

```
 var attendanceInfoDupilicate = [AttendanceInfo]()
```

Inside of the Json service call at end

```
self.attendanceInfoDupilicate = self.attendanceInfo
```

updater the search controller

```
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController)
    {



        let searchToSeatch = AttendanceSearchBarController.searchBar.text

        if(searchToSeatch == "")
        {
            self.attendanceInfo = self.attendanceInfoDupilicate

        }
        else{

            self.attendanceInfo.removeAll()

            let AttedanceData = self.attendanceInfoDupilicate

            var kidsArray = [String]()

            for AttendanceInfo in AttedanceData
            {

                kidsArray.append(AttendanceInfo.name)
                if(AttendanceInfo.name.range(of: searchToSeatch!, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil)
                {
                    self.attendanceInfo.append(AttendanceInfo)

                }

            }




        }

        self.TableView.reloadData()


    }
```